# How to assign html values from php?

Tags: php, html

I want to show this values in index.html

How to get html values from php?
display.php codes as following

```
require "conn2.php";

$id = $_POST['s_id'];

echo $id;


$mysql_qry = "select * from Questions where Id='$id'";
$disp = mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_qry);

if(mysqli_num_rows($disp) > 0){
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($disp);
    //echo"<br/> Question id: " .$result['Id'];
    echo"<br/> Question: <br/>" .$result['Question'];

    $mysql_qry = "select * from Answers where ForeignKey='$id'";
    $disp2 = mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_qry);
    while($result2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($disp2)){
        //echo"<br/> Answer id: " .$result2['Id'];
        echo"<br/>      " .$result2['Answer'];
        //echo"<br/> Value: " .$result2['Value'];
    }
}
```

index.html codes as following

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title of html</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="display.php" method="POST">
        <p>Enter the id of question</p><input type="text" name="s_id"><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="show me">
    </form>

</body>
```

and it works like
[display.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/545pe.png)
[index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qBWf.png)

Comment: write the code here

Comment: please post your code as a text, don't put it as image

Comment: Fix what? You have errors? Unexpected behaviour? Or what?

Comment: Have you checked your query works? Shouldn't it be
 
`$mysql_qry = "select * from Questions where Id=" . $id;`

Comment: yeah query is working

Comment: Cool, and what does **not** work?

Comment: can you print `print_r(mysqli_error($conn));` after both mysql_query & check if any error shows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"I want to show this values in index.html"*

You will either need to instruct your server to treat `.html` files "as php" through `.htaccess` if your server supports it, or rename your `.html` file to `.php`, or use an ajax call.

You could also use an [`<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) with the source being an `.php` file.

You also need to run this off a webserver through localhost and not as `file:///` after seeing some of your screenshots in https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43834696/5 --- https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Axrz.png.

Your code is also open to an SQL injection; use a prepared statement:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Comment: this is so helpful thank you for your feedback also you are right it is open to sql injection :)

Comment: OPs site seems to be a `000webapps` site rather than a local `file:///`

Comment: @Martin I based myself on their original post http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43834696/1 with the screenshot of https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Axrz.png - that's why I wrote that. Edit: and another revision after that.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I saw the original post was a Notepad++ screenshot, (but really I just wanted an excuse to coverse with your good self `;-)`)

Comment: @Martin *Haha!* - well, you can always invite / ping me into a chatroom. Just not sure if I'll be able to chat for long, but you can always try. Always a pleasure conversing with you also.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want the page to refresh and only work on index.html you can get the result with ajax in to your index.html.

To do this In your index.html include the jquery and then you can retrieve data from php file like this.
In index.html

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Title of html</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
            <form id="displayform"  method="POST">
              <p>Enter the id of question</p><input type="text" name="s_id"><br/>
              <input type="submit" name="submit" value="show me">
            </form>
            Result: 
            <div id="result">

            </div>

      </body>
    </html>


        <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#displayform").submit(function(e) {
                //prevent Default functionality
                e.preventDefault();

                $.ajax({
                        url: 'display.php',
                        type: 'post',
                        dataType: 'html',
                        data: $("#displayform").serialize(),
                        success: function(response) {
                            $("#result").html(response);
                        }
                });

            });

        });
        </script>
```